# Exact semantics of build_always_stale?

Tags: meson-build

It seems that whenever a `build_always_stale: true` target is rebuilt, it is also assumed to be *changed* by the rebuild, even if the output file is factually bit-for-bit unchanged. This causes targets *depending* on the `build_always_stale` target to also be rebuilt every time. Is this part of the semantics of `build_always_stale`?

I thought that `build_always_stale` just meant "we don't know how to determine whether this target is up to date, so please always rebuild it just in case", but it seems it also includes "and please consider the result to be always changed even if it isn't"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this part of the semantics of `build_always_stale`?

That's up to the underlying build system to decide. On its end, meson just makes sure that the target is always rebuilt, no matter what.

---

Taking the `ninja` backend as an example, and taking a look at the [`generate_custom_target`](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/17dd9e5bffd42c3ad6c2dff1f15639d6adf31e1c/mesonbuild/backend/ninjabackend.py#L668) function in its source code in particular, you'll see this:

```py
if target.build_always_stale:
    deps.append('PHONY')
```

Which means that, if a custom target is marked as always stale, meson will tell ninja to add `PHONY` as its dependency.

In that case, ninja will always assume that the target is out of date, and thus that all of *its* dependents are out of date as well.

---

Comment: Is it the semantics of ninja's 'PHONY' that all targets depending on it directly **and indirectly** are always considered outdated? My understanding is that whether a target is up to date should only depend on its _direct_ dependencies. If a dependency is bit-for-bit the same as the dependent target, then that dependency shouldn't trigger rebuilding the dependent target, **even** if the dependency was just idempotently rebuilt.

Comment: Correction: If a dependency is bit-for-bit the same as *the version used to build* the dependent target...

Comment: Just dropping by to add that my question grew from my incorrect assumption that ninja used hashes rather than timestamps. It uses timestamps, and whenever something is rebuilt its timestamp changes, end of story. I accepted your answer because it made me realize my error.